# Is there a good way to check if a link is a bad link?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

On my page, there is a download link. I want to check if this link is a good link, which means the user can really download the file they want. If the link doesn't work, then I want to provide the user another back-up link.

The problem I have is I don't know how to check if the link is a good link or bad link.

Comment: You'd have to preload the link and check it periodically. Have you tried that?

Comment: What is behind that link? A file? a Script?  How about handling that in the backend? maybe redirecting with mod_rewrite or a script. What kind of backend do you have? Don't do this in the frontend, since it will only stress your customers internet-connection/volume; And your server of course.

Comment: @Thomas I am using php as the backend. Behind the link, it's an apk file.

Comment: @EdCottrell How do you preload the link? Do I check the link periodically in the backend or frontend?

Comment: @SSD You would need to do it on the backend, and you would need to use a library like cURL. How exactly to do it is much too broad a question for this site.